# How to track all the events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a GA setup on my website. It is working fine.

Now I am planning to add save the post feature on my site. So every user can save n number of posts through there account. I want to implement a tracking system such a way that Google will count each event OR each post save event by any user. Currently, Google does track the only one event, regardless user saves 15 posts from their account.

So is there any way I can set up GA such a way that Google will show all the tracking events instead of unique user results?

Eg. If 10 users save 10 jobs then in GA, I should be able to see 100 click events not just 10 events.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Analytics sends all the events you configure, so you need to send an event for each job saved. You have to make a custom function with a loop called after click on save button passing the number of jobs saved.